# Why does .net8.0 append a hash to the version number?

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I compile and publish a .NET executable like this:

```
dotnet publish ..\code\cbutils\cbutils.csproj -c Release -f net8.0 -r win-x64 -o D:\work\install\cbutils /property:Version=1.2.3.1096 --self-contained
```

In net6 this returned the version I expected. However in net8.0 it appends a hash to the version, like this:

```
$ cbutils --version
1.2.3.1096+5caefb1c5d44de91af147031c3c4325e0ab5aec2
```

Where is this hash coming from and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: It does! Thanks for the pointer, not sure how I missed this thread.